# Выбор элементов из массива

Tags: c#

Есть массив `string` элементов 
например:

```
mas[0] = "1_30092016_12";
mas[1] = "2_30092016_13";
mas[2] = "3_30022016_14";
mas[3] = "4_30012016_15";
```

Как выбрать из него элементы по дате(вторая часть имени после _)?

Comment: А вас не смущает, что у вас одна из дат - 30-ое февраля? ))

Comment: @Astronavigator, это как в произведении "12 месяцев", пока мы не выполним это задание, то будет 30 февраля, 31 февраля, 32 фе.....

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] mas = new string[] 
{ 
    "1_30092016_12", 
    "2_30092016_13", 
    "3_30022016_14", 
    "4_30012016_15" 
};
foreach (var i in mas)
{
    string[] myArray = i.Split('_');
    Console.WriteLine(myArray[1]); // второй элемент массива содержит строки с датами
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут Вам пример и `String.Format` и `Linq` и работа с `DateTime`, изучайте на здоровье

```
mas.Where(x=>x.Contains(string.Format("_{0}_", (new DateTime(2016, 9, 30)).ToString("ddMMyyyy"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SearchDate()
{
    string[] mas = new string[] { "1_30092016_12", "2_30092016_13", "3_30022016_14", "4_30012016_15" };
    string search = "30012016";

    for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++ )
    {
        if (mas[i].Contains(search))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(mas[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться LINQ. В простейшем случае выбор элемента по дате будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
var m = from s in mas where s.Contains("30022016") select s;
textBox1.Text = m.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: а если у меня 2 записи с таким же числом но разными индексами как вывести все?

Comment: @SideKick, воспользоваться `string.Join`

Comment: а можно с примером? несколько дней в C#))